# Fedora OS structure change

Tags: fedora, directory-structure

I recently noticed that the structure of **16**:

http://redhat.download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/x86_64/os/

is different from **17**:

http://redhat.download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/x86_64/os/

Has something significant changed in the way that Fedora is packaged, and if so does this effect auto install tools that read from the os/ directory?  For example, virt-install.

Comment: You might want to look at the Fedora site and checkout the changes as I'm not sure people here will have an answer for your.

Comment: I don't see the big issue, the important parts seems to be still there (e.g. `EFI`, `images`, `Packages`, `isolinux` etc.) the gpg keys are probably irrelevant for virt-install

Answer (score 1):

As @UlrichDangel mentioned in the comments there really isn't that much of a difference:

**F16 vs. F17 side-by-side structure**

```
16                                      17
---                                     ---
EFI/                                    EFI/
GPL
                                        LiveOS/
Packages/                               Packages/
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-16-primary
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-16-secondary
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-arm
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-i386
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-ppc
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-ppc64
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-s390
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-s390x
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-sparc
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-sparc64
RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-x86_64
images/                                 images/
isolinux/                               isolinux/
repodata/                               repodata/
repoview/                               repoview/
```

Other than the GPL notice and the GPG keys for RPM and the LiveOS they're essentially identical.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  The problem Im having is related to missing "product.img" files in the fedora install / download.  This is happening when I attempt to virt-install.

Comment: You might be able to use `updates.img`. Take a look at [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Changes) & [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Updates). Also double check inside the ISO. According to [this](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Installation_Guide/s1-steps-hd-installs-x86.html) it might be in there. That's where it was in F15, according to [this](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Installation_Guide/s1-steps-hd-installs-x86.html) it might not be includes anymore, it's unclear to me as well.